# UICollectionView cell loads one image on top of another image

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiimageview, didselectrowatindexpath

I had everything working perfectly in test.

In production, a user saved a few images, two are ok but for some reason, two are doubling up on top of another image.

When tapping on the image (didSelectItemAt)

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Gets called and each tap, changes the image to clear it up into just one image.

I've worked back from this point but I'm stuck.

Images loaded in viewDidLoad

```
db.collection("SAVED IMAGE IDS").getDocuments()
{
    (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err
    {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    }
    else
    {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents
        {
            let id = document.documentID
                
            let Ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "SavedUserImages/\(id)")

            Ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024)
            {
                data, error in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print("Error: Image could not download!")
                }
                else
                {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    
                    self.picArray.append(image!)
                          
                    self.imageID.append(id)
                            
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image loads in cell for row

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        
     let data = picArray[indexPath.row]
        
     cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
     cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        
     let iv = UIImageView()
     cell.contentView.addSubview(iv)
     iv.frame = cell.contentView.frame
     iv.image = data
        
     collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .init())
        
     return cell
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code:

[image]

you are adding ***another image view*** every time you reload the cell.

Instead, you need to design your cell to *already have the image view* and change your code to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        
     let data = picArray[indexPath.row]
        
     cell.iv.image = data
        
     return cell
}
```

---

**Edit** - *further explanation and examples...*

Based on the code you've shown, you are using a default `UICollectionViewCell` instead of a custom subclassed cell.

So, if we do a complete example, using SF Symbol images from 0 to 14 for the `picArray`, using *your* approach:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    let cellID: String = "cell"
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var cvWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    // let's use an array of images for this example
    var picArray: [UIImage] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create images 0 through 14
        for i in 0..<15 {
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(i).circle") {
                picArray.append(img)
            }
        }
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .vertical
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        // it appears you're using a default collection view cell class
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // only do this is the collection view frame has changed
        if cvWidth != collectionView.frame.width {
            cvWidth = collectionView.frame.width
            if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                fl.itemSize = CGSize(width: cvWidth, height: 200.0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return picArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        let data = picArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        // this is wrong... we're Adding ANOTHER image view every time
        let iv = UIImageView()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(iv)
        iv.frame = cell.contentView.frame
        iv.image = data

        // this makes no sense, but I'll leave it here
        collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .init())

        return cell
    }
    
}
```

It looks like this at the start:

[image]

if we scroll all the way down - to where the "14" image should be the bottom cell, it looks like this:

[image]

If we scroll back to the top:

[image]

and after scrolling up and down several times:

[image]

As we can see, as the cells are **reused** we keep adding more and more image views on top of each other.

So, instead, let's create a simple custom cell subclass that creates and adds an image view *when it is created*:

```
class SimpleImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(imgView)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

and we'll use an almost identical view controller - the only differences are registering our `SimpleImageCell` class, and using a correct `cellForItemAt` func:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    let cellID: String = "cell"
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var cvWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    // let's use an array of images for this example
    var picArray: [UIImage] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create images 0 through 14
        for i in 0..<15 {
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(i).circle") {
                picArray.append(img)
            }
        }
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .vertical
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        // register cell class that already has an image view
        collectionView.register(SimpleImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // only do this is the collection view frame has changed
        if cvWidth != collectionView.frame.width {
            cvWidth = collectionView.frame.width
            if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                fl.itemSize = CGSize(width: cvWidth, height: 200.0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return picArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! SimpleImageCell
        
        let data = picArray[indexPath.item]
        cell.imgView.image = data
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

The results:

[image] [image]

We can scroll up and down all we want, and we will never have images "on top of" each other.

Comment: That way caused big issues, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341904/loading-images-into-uicollectionview-from-firebase-storage + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370260/how-to-populate-a-uicollectionview-with-images-loaded-from-firebase-storage .I was stuck for a few days until I figured out the only way it would seem to work. Everything was working perfectly until a user from another country added images, they added 4, two are ok, always the top and bottom of the 4, the middle two of the 4 images are the ones that always double loads. The advice in the question, was the same issue

Comment: I understand you've tried to help twice, thank you. I have everything working the way I have it, the ways you tell me may be the right way to do it but this way was working perfectly until another user added images.

Comment: @dajmispokój - it doesn't matter if it *"works most of the time"* ... that is the **wrong** way to do this. The proof it's the wrong way is that ***it doesn't work some of the time!*** You never followed up on your other question you linked to (deleted now), so I have no idea what you mean by *"That way caused big issues"*? However, see the **Edit** to my answer for a quick example of how to do this the right way.

Comment: I remember when you helped me with a question a year or two ago, I  then found out you were a genius. Putting the imageView in a separate CollectionView Class solved it. The imageView placed anywhere else was causing issues, maybe because everything else is all in one class? Either way, I really appreciate the time you've spent to solve my problem, DonMag, Thank you.